# Problema al insertar datos en mysql con código PHP, You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, csv

estoy bloqueado en un punto ya que me salta

Error: INSERT INTO empresas (NOMBRE, DIRECCION, TELEFONO, GREVIEWS, GSCORE, FECHA_EXTRAC) VALUES (DIA, Carrer dels Comtes d'Urgell 4, 912 17 04 53, htwitter.coom/DIA, 11, 3.1)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'dels Comtes d'Urgell 4, 912 17 04 53, htwitter.com/DIA, 11, 3.1)' at line 1

Las cabeceras son exactamente las mismas que las de la base de datos y el nombre de la tabla es la correcta. La conexión es correcta, el archivo csv desde donde extraigo los datos es correcto... Pero aun así no consigo introducir los datos en la tabla. Llevo horas detras del problema. adjunto codigo

```html
<?php
//hacemos la conexión con nuestra BD indicamos el  nombre del archivo y leemos y guardamos en un array llamados linea y cerramos
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "prueba4bis");

 if(!$con){
  echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
  echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
  echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
  exit;
 }

echo "Exito: Se realizo una conexion apropiada a MySQL! La base de datos mi_bd es estupentastica.<br />" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Informacion del host: <br />" . mysqli_get_host_info($con) . PHP_EOL;

ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);

$info=fopen("generalCSV.csv" , "r" );
 if(!$info){
  echo "Error al abrir el archivo<br />" . PHP_EOL; 
 } else {
   echo "</br>El archivo se ha abierto correctamente<br />";
  }
  
 echo"</br>";

 $miarray[16] = array();
 
 for($i=0;$i<=999;$i++){
  $datos=fgetcsv($info,100000,",",'"');
  $NOMBREx=$datos[0];
  $DIRECCIONx=$datos[1];
  $LOCALIDADx=$datos[2];
  $PROVINCIAx=$datos[3];
  $CODIGO_POSTALx=$datos[4];
  $TELEFONOx=$datos[5];
  $EMAILx=$datos[6];
  $WEBSITEx=$datos[7];
  $FBx=$datos[8];
  $TWITTERx=$datos[9];
  $G_REVIEWSx=$datos[10];
  $G_SCOREx=$datos[11];
  $FECHA_EXTRACx=$datos[12];
  $CCAAx=$datos[13];
  $CATEGORIAx=$datos[14];
  $ACTIVIDADx=$datos[15];
  $PAQ_PSx=$datos[16];
  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO empresas (NOMBRE, DIRECCION, TELEFONO, GREVIEWS, GSCORE, FECHA_EXTRAC) VALUES ($NOMBREx, $DIRECCIONx, $TELEFONOx, $G_REVIEWSx, $G_SCOREx, $FECHA_EXTRACx)";
   if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "Nuevo registro insertado correctamente CHAVAAAAAL!";
   } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
     }
  echo"</br>";
  echo"</br>";
 }
 
 //////COMPROBAMOS QUE LA FUCION fgetcsv() LEE CORRECTAMENTE.

  if(!$datos){
  echo"Error al leer los datos con fgetcsv<br />".PHP_EOL;
 } else{
   echo"Lectura con fgetcsv correcta<br />".PHP_EOL;
  }
  
 fclose($info);
 ?>
```

y la salida es:

Exito: Se realizo una conexion apropiada a MySQL! La base de datos mi_bd es estupentastica.
Informacion del host:
localhost via TCP/IP
El archivo se ha abierto correctamente

Error: INSERT INTO empresas (NOMBRE, DIRECCION, TELEFONO, GREVIEWS, GSCORE, FECHA_EXTRAC) VALUES (DIA, Carrer dels Comtes d'Urgell 4, 912 17 04 53, https://twitter.com/DIA, 11, 3.1)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'dels Comtes d'Urgell 4, 912 17 04 53, https://twitter.com/DIA, 11, 3.1)' at line 1

Error: INSERT INTO empresas (NOMBRE, DIRECCION, TELEFONO, GREVIEWS, GSCORE, FECHA_EXTRAC) VALUES (Dia Market, Carrer de les Corts Catalanes, 58, 912 17 04 53, https://twitter.com/DIA, 46, 3.6)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Market, Carrer de les Corts Catalanes, 58, 912 17 04 53, https://twitter.com/DIA' at line 1

Comment: Es mejor que uses consultas preparadas, el problema parece residir en la forma en que se están insertando los caracteres como `,` y `'`. Al menos es lo que me parece que sucede.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu problema es que los campos tipo varchar deben ir entre comillas simples.. o usas consultas preparadas (la mejor idea) o mandas cada campo como corresponde...

Answer (score 0):

El problema es por el apostrofe en NOMBRE

Prueba con esto

```
 $NOMBREx = addslashes($datos[0])
```

Y para la hora de mostrar los datos en pantalla, prueba con esto

```
stripslashes($str);
```

NOTA: Te recomiendo que apliques la función para todas la variables